# Check the services in linux server from windows using batch scripts

Tags: linux, unix, batch-file

This is about to check the linux services using batch scripts.

We have a Linux server with windows as a client machine. We are using windows server for all data loads using batch scripts. We want to check the Linux services before starts the loads using batch scripts from windows daily with batch scripts.

Question is that, can we write the batch script to check the services in Linux services and if yes, can we get any services is not up then the batch scripts has to `goto exit` option else it `goto next` step, can we?

please give your views on this. thanks Nag

Comment: Hmm I've done something similar, but I used perl to execute commands on linux servers through SSH.

Comment: off topic, move your question in unix-linux sister's site or at least in superuser site.

Answer (score 0):

you can install the cygin https://cygwin.com/install.html on windows box. you can run the shell command on the cygwin prompt on windows box. 
for eg:
service sshd status > status.txt

and then you can use status.txt as a input file to your batch script to check the status.